# Realm transaction using from different thread

Tags: android, realm

I have writeToRealm method that I use very often. And I need to use it from different threads and cut boilerplate code. What is the better way for this task?

```
private boolean writeToRealm(String user, String id) {

        SubscriberObject subscriber = new SubscriberObject();

        if(mRealm.where(SubscriberObject.class)
                .equalTo(SubscriberObject.ID,id).findAll().isEmpty()
                &&mRealm.where(SubscriberObject.class)
               .equalTo(SubscriberObject.USERNAME,user).findAll().isEmpty()) {
            subscriber.setId(id);
            subscriber.setUsername(user);
            mRealm.beginTransaction();
            mRealm.insert(subscriber);
            mRealm.commitTransaction();
            return true;
        }
        return  false;
```

}

I am planning to use construction below (or something like this) but I can't create a correct construction:

```
  public static Boolean writeToRealm(final String user,final String id){
        Realm mRealm;
        return Flowable.using(
                mRealm = Realm.getDefaultInstance(),
                new Function<Realm, Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public Boolean apply(@NonNull Realm realm) throws Exception {
                        SubscriberObject subscriber = new SubscriberObject();
                        if(realm.where(SubscriberObject.class)
                                .equalTo(SubscriberObject.ID,id).findAll().isEmpty()
                                &&realm.where(SubscriberObject.class)
                                .equalTo(SubscriberObject.USERNAME,user).findAll().isEmpty()) {
                            subscriber.setId(id);
                            subscriber.setUsername(user);
                            realm.beginTransaction();
                            realm.insert(subscriber);
                            realm.commitTransaction();
                            return true;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                },
                mRealm.close()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    }
```

Or may be I need to create a thread class with looper for this task?

How to better integrate this method and similar methods into a clean architecture?

Comment: please prefer using executeTransaction() and also, spawning a new thread and getting a realm object for the first time is a heavy operation, I would recommend you to use an ExecutorService

Comment: Sarthak Mittal, I thought about it but still we have to create an instance each time and we need looper for controlling changes.

Comment: if you need a non-UI thread as well as looper then HandlerThread will be the way to go! :)

Comment: This isn't my desire, this Realm requirement. Yes, but adding a handler to clean architecture it's not so easy :)

Comment: And another, instance of the HandlerThread needs to be created and killed in each component, it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just looking for

```
private boolean writeToRealm(String user, String id) {
    try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {           
        if(realm.where(SubscriberObject.class).equalTo(SubscriberObject.ID,id).count() <= 0L 
              && realm.where(SubscriberObject.class).equalTo(SubscriberObject.USERNAME,user).count() <= 0L) {
            final SubscriberObject subscriber = new SubscriberObject();
            subscriber.setId(id);
            subscriber.setUsername(user);
            realm.executeTransaction(r -> r.insert(subscriber));
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: EpicPandaForce thank you for your help and answers. I can't understand one issue. How to work with this method if i want to use not UI thread and not Async method, only threads that I create? The Realm academy doesn't describe the looper work detailed. For example: If I start new Thread method or Flowable.subscribeOn and put "there" writeToRealm method (to this thread). At what moment the changes will be saved? Can I save them before closing realm instance? Will it work correctly in a thread without a looper?

Comment: This is a synchronous method call, there is no reason to make it Flowable.

Comment: Yes, I understand it. But If I write a lot of data and I wan't to use UI thread and Async method too. For example, I start new Thread (new Runnable...writeToRealm) What problems can be associated with this approach?  in the example it was necessary to close a realm instance? Also I added comment below.

Comment: `try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) { ... }` auto-closes the realm (Try-with-resources)

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be way an easier solution:

```
public static Boolean writeToRealm(String user, String id) {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    SubscriberObject subscriber = new SubscriberObject();
    if (realm.where(SubscriberObject.class).equalTo("ID", id).or().equalTo("USERNAME", user).findAll().isEmpty()){
        subscriber.setId(id);
        subscriber.setUsername(user);
        realm.beginTransaction();
        realm.insert(subscriber);
        realm.commitTransaction();
        realm.close();
        return true;
    }
    realm.close();
    return false;
}
```

If you need some explainations, just tell me and I will implement it :)

PS: if I missunderstood your question, let me know!

Comment: Pier Giorgio Misley, can you explain your answer? Please, read my two comments above.

Answer (score 0):

> The asynchronous transaction support works the same way as the current executeTransaction, but instead of opening a Realm on the same thread, it will give you a background Realm opened on a different thread. You can also register a callback if you wish to be notified when the transaction completes or fails.

```
    realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        Dog dog = realm.where(Dog.class).equalTo("age", 1).findFirst();
        dog.setName("Fido");
    }
}, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        Log.d("REALM", "All done updating.");
        Log.d("BG", t.getName());
    }
}, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable error) {
        // transaction is automatically rolled-back, do any cleanup here
    }
});
```

[read more](https://academy.realm.io/posts/threading-deep-dive/)

Comment: This way isn't good because of two reasons. The first one - we should control realm instance (create/ close) from another thread and we can forgot to close it. The second one -  async realm pool has limitations. It means when we have async threads more than the limit the task will be waiting.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't have `boolean` return type if you want to do your transaction asynchronously. You will have to use either `Interface` pass result back to caller or you have to opt for some other means like RxJava.

just to give you example.

The RxJava way(As this would be simplest way):

```
public static Flowable<Boolean> writeToRealm(final String user,final String id) {
    return Flowable.fromCallable(
        new Callable<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call() throws Exception {
                Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                if(realm.where(SubscriberObject.class)
                    .equalTo(SubscriberObject.ID,id).findAll().isEmpty()
                    &&realm.where(SubscriberObject.class)
                    .equalTo(SubscriberObject.USERNAME,user).findAll().isEmpty()) {
                    SubscriberObject subscriber = new SubscriberObject();
                    subscriber.setId(id);
                    subscriber.setUsername(user);
                    realm.beginTransaction();
                    realm.insert(subscriber);
                    realm.commitTransaction();
                    mRealm.close();
                    return true;
                }
                mRealm.close();
                return false;
        }
    });
}
```

You subscribe the returned `Flowable` on desired thread/schedular to perform transaction on that particular thread.

Comment: Kalpesh Patel what about Looper? I know If we don't have a looper in the thread, the changes will not happen. And we should control the thread has a looper or not? But how to do it correctly?

Comment: which changes you mean?

Comment: I spoke about changes in database. At what moment does the database change? Close or committransaction? (in non Looper thread) For example, If we have 2 threads - UI and background (non looper), from these threads we change the same element. How would this happen?